# Setting up a radiation heat transfer problem

Tags: heat-transfer

I am trying to solve a radiation heat transfer problem. The problem is set up like this: Two spherical shells of radius R whose surfaces are separated by a distance R. One shell, call it A, has a steady heat flux of Q and the other, call it B, does not. Both also radiate to ambient ('surface' C) at 0 C.

To solve this I use these equations:

$$ \dot{q}_i = \frac{\varepsilon_i A_i (E_{b,i}-J_i)}{1-\varepsilon_i} \quad \text{for } i = 1.. N $$
$$ \dot{q}_i = A_i \sum_{j=1}^N F_{i,j}(J_i-Jj)  \quad \text{for } i = 1.. N $$

So for sphere A, the left hand side of both equations is Q and for the others it is zero. The view factors are as follows:

FAB = 0.0294

FAC = 1-FAB

FBA = FAB

FBC = FAC

FCA = FAC*SurfaceAreaA/SurfaceAreaC

FCB = FBCC*SurfaceAreaA/SurfaceAreaC

FBC = FAC

Since the temperature of C is set, I have 6 equations in 5 unknowns (TA, TB, JA, JB, JC).  When I try to solve this in matlab using the nonlinear equation solver I cannot get a solution.  Did I make a mistake in setting this up?

Below is the matlab code I am using for equations 1 and 2.

```
function F = TWO_SPHERES_AMBIENT(J)
% Function called by FSOLVE

sig = 5.670374419e-8;    % S-B constant [W/m^2*K^4]
r = 0.1;                 % Radius of Balls A and B [m]
R = 10;                  % Radius of "Ambient" sphere
g = 50000;               % Equiv. Internal Generation of Ball A [W/m^3]
vol = 4*pi*(r^3)/3;      % [m^3]
sa = 4*pi*(r^2);         % Surface Area of Balls A and B [m^2]
SA = 4*pi*(R^2);         % Surface Area of "Ambient" Sphere [m^2]
totgen = g*vol;          % Total Heat Generated in Ball A [W]
flux2surf = totgen/sa;   % Total Flux to the Surface of Ball A [W/m^2]
eps1 = 0.7;              % Generating ball emis.
eps2 = 0.5;              % Nongenerating ball emis.
eps3 = 0.99;             % "Ambient" emis. (1, Except Div. By Zero Below)
FAB = 0.0294;            % View Factors
FAC = 1 - FAB;
FBA = FAB;
FBC = FAC;
FCA = FAC*sa/SA;
FCB = FBC*sa/SA;
FCC = 1 - FCA - FCB;     % Plays no role in equations below. (J(3)-J(3)=0)
FBC = FAC;
% BELOW IS IS THE RETURN TO FSOLVE. J IS WHAT FSOLVE PASSES IN, F IS
% RETURNED BACK.
% J(1) IS BALL A RADIOSITY 
% J(2) IS BALL B RADIOSITY
% J(3) IS 'AMBIENT' RADIOSITY
% J(4) IS BALL A TEMPERATURE
% J(5) IS BALL A TEMPERATURE
% J(6) IS "Ambient" TEMPERATURE
% EQUATIONS 1, SET TO ZERO AS REQUIRED BY FSOLVE.
F(1) = sa*(FAB*(J(1) - J(2)) + FAC*(J(1) - J(3))) - totgen;
F(2) = sa*(FBA*(J(2) - J(1)) + FBC*(J(2) - J(3)));
F(3) = SA*(FCA*(J(3) - J(1)) + FCB*(J(3) - J(2)));
% EQUATIONs 2, SET TO ZERO AS REQUIRED BY FSOLVE 
F(4) = eps1*sa*(sig*J(4).^4 - J(1))/(1-eps1) - totgen;
F(5) = eps2*sa*(sig*J(5).^4 - J(2))/(1-eps2);
F(6) = eps3*SA*(sig*273.15.^4 - J(3))/(1-eps3);
```

Comment: This site supports LaTeX if inline equations are surrounded by dollar signs and displayed equations with double dollar signs: $\dot{q}_i=\frac{\varepsilon_iA_i(E_{b,i}-J_i)}{(1-\varepsilon_i)}$. Please include the equations you derived to permit review. These are generally in the form of $\frac{E_{bi}-J_i}{(1-\varepsilon_i)/\varepsilon_iA_i}=\Sigma_{j=1}^N\frac{J_i-J_j}{(A_iF_{ij})^{-1}}$.

Comment: Ok, I will add the matlab code I used.

Comment: Note I keep the equations 1 and 2 separated  so that I have 6 equations in 6 unknowns (even though the ambient temperature is actually known).  You would end up with only 3 equations by combining them.

Comment: Any help on this problem?

Comment: Can you be more precise than "I cannot get a solution."? How do you know the problem isn't in MATLAB's solution module, for example, rather than the formulation? Are you able to solve a simpler problem (e.g., one source and one sink) in MATLAB?

Comment: I mean no matter what initial guesses I try, matlab says no solution is found.  I want to check some results from ansys with this code, since I don't trust the ansys results. When I use the ansys results as the initial guess I still get no solution found..

Comment: Why do you have an area for the ambient environment? I'm not saying your approach is wrong, and maybe it all cancels out to be equivalent in the end, but I'm used to seeing the reciprocity relation used to turn, e.g., $A_CF_{CA}$ into $A_AF_{AC}$. A diagram would be helpful.

Comment: The code is commented well I think. I used a sphere of radius 10 meters as the ambient. Each sphere has radius 0.1 m.

Comment: What does MATLAB give if you set the appropriate parameters to zero to give the simpler case of A alone radiating into an infinite void at 0 K?

Comment: I still do not know what "trying to solve a radiation heat transfer problem" means. Define the terms in the analytical equation using a system picture. State what you have and what you will set as the unknowns. Until then, I am unconvinced that you have something solvable. Your code uses symbols that are not anywhere in the analytical equations. You may therefore not even have the correct translation from the analytical equations to code. Finally, as near as I see in the (unclear) code, all the heat input to A is going to B. Perhaps the code is wrong because the system equations are invalid?

Comment: Unclear code?  Literally every line is commented individually or explained in group comments!